# Questions on $x^2+y^2+z^2$, $x^2+y^2+2z^2$ and $x^2+2y^2+3z^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms, sums-of-squares

**Question 1.** My computation in 2018 suggests that a sum of two integer squares is a sum of three nonzero integer squares if and only if it is not of the form
$$4^km\ \ (k=0,1,2,\ldots;\ \ m=1,2,5,10,13,25,37,58,85,130).$$
How to prove this?

I have two similar questions formulated in 2018.

**Question 2.** If a positive integer $n\not=1,5,29,65$ is a sum of two squares, how to prove that $n=x^2+y^2+2z^2$ for some integers $x,y,z$ with $z\not=0$?

**Question 3.** If a positive integer $n\not=1,17,2^{2k+1}\ (k=0,1,2,\ldots)$ has the form $x^2+2y^2$ with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, can one show that $n=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$ for some integers $x,y,z$ with $z\not=0$? If a positive integer $n\not=4^k,4^k\times7,4^k\times13$ $(k=0,1,2,\ldots)$ has the form $x^2+3y^2$ with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, can one show that $n=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$ for some integers $x,y,z$ with $y\not=0$?

Answer (score 6):

Problems like Question 1 go back to Euler and Gauss.  This question is essentially asking which *idoneal* numbers are sums of two squares.  There is a famous open problem going back to Euler and Gauss asking for a complete list of idoneal numbers (equivalently discriminants with one class per genus); the list is known to be finite with one more possible idoneal numbers but this is ineffective.  On GRH one would have the Euler/Gauss conjecture.

Similar results hold for these problems.  The connection in the context of sums of three positive squares was explicitly fleshed out by [Grosswald, Calloway, and Calloway](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/14f0/7a7d3f84917e20ae9f32930a78940f6e5df2.pdf?_ga=2.247923079.1684743662.1604548506-907611811.1603153491) (Proc. AMS 1959, vol 10, 451--455), who formulate a version of Question 1 as a conjecture.

Comment: It is a common error to bungle the equivalence between idoneal numbers and fundamental discriminants with one class per genus. In fact, Weinberger proved there is at most one more fundamental discriminant $D$ with one class per genus, but if $8|D$ there will be two more idoneal numbers (and if $4\|D$ there is one, and if $D$ is odd, there are none). I think Kani has the best writeup (Theorem 22 in 2.6). https://mast.queensu.ca/~kani/papers/idoneal-f.pdf